# Can t.me links be malicious?

Tags: telegram

I clicked inadvertently on this link in a telegram channel - a popoup window says “user doesn’t exist”.

A virustotal scan did not find anything. Do you think this kind of link could be used to execute some kind of malicious script?

[image: tg link]

Comment: This is not the site to get an evaluation for specific links. Apart from that content behind links can easily be changed or can be specific to the location of the user or other criteria. So one cannot be sure that the site is not malicious just because someone else visiting the site (like virustotal) does not find anything malicious there.

Comment: Thanks, I get it. My question was about the type of a link, not this specific link

Answer (score 5):

[t.me/something URLs](https://telegramguide.com/what-is-t-me-in-telegram/) link to telegram channels and profiles and are normally 100% safe.

This is not a URL shortening service, it's a Telegram feature to share Telegram channels not only with people who have the app installed but those who don't - the latter could open the link in a web browser and preview it.

Telegram users and channels can be deleted/deactivated/banned - that's exactly what you saw.